# How to create a custom arraylist with custom methods

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

I was asked this question in an interview.

How do we create a custom `ArrayList` with all the methods implemented in the `ArrayList` except for the `remove`, `removeAll()` method?

So, my `ArrayList` implementation must not have these two methods.

One solution I got was to extend my class to the `ArrayList` class and implement all the methods except the `remove()` and `removeAll()` method.

I am not sure if this is the right way.

Comment: To clarify, I'm assuming your solution is to create a class (eg. `MyCustomArrayList`) that *extends* `ArrayList` and then overrides the `remove()` and `removeAll()` methods to be no-ops. (Please correct me if that assumption is inaccurate). If so, that seems like a fine solution. Were you looking for alternate solutions?

Comment: This is the solution that I thought, but the interviewer specifically wanted my custom ArrayList not to have these methods.

Comment: Were you allowed to modify the `ArrayList` class? Were you required to subclass the `ArrayList` class specifically?

Comment: If your *type* is `List` or `ArrayList`, then you would have `remove` and `removeAll` methods

Comment: If you extend ArrayList class but do not implement remove and removeall methods still your class will inherit these two methods from  ArrayList class. Either you can override these methods and throw UnsupportedOperationException or extend AbstractList class which itself will throw UnsupportedOperationException

Comment: Assuming the methods must not be present at all—and not simply throw some exception when invoked—then the only way is to create your own `ArrayList` which does not implement `List` (or `Collection`).

Comment: An alternative would be to create a customArrayList class but instead of extending ArrayList you create a private field ArrayList. And then provide all the method of arrayList to that class (for example `public void add(int el){ arr.add(el); }`. But not remove and removeAll. This seems reasonable and you don't need to throw UnsupportedOperationException so code would be nicer. But you will have to implement all the other methods, which you would not have to do if you extended.

Comment: Another way is to grab the source code of `ArrayList`, remove the `extends` clause and remove both `remove` and `removeAll`. Not that it is a good habit, but it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend `ArrayList` and override specified methods like **unsupported methods**. They implementation is going to throw [`UnsupportedOperationException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html) and nothing else.

```java
class NoRemoveArrayList extends ArrayList {

    @Override
    public Object remove(int i) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeAll(Collection collection) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Search for growable array (data structure). You will get complete details and how to do it.